# Is there a way to remove the default GWT theme completely?

Tags: java, gwt, gwt2

I would like to start GWT Project without GWT Themes, is there a way to tune off default theme like clean.css?

Answer (score 1):

In your *.gwt.xml file you may be inheriting a theme.  e.g.

```
  <!-- Inherit the default GWT style sheet.  You can change       -->
  <!-- the theme of your GWT application by uncommenting          -->
  <!-- any one of the following lines.                            -->
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard' />
  <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.chrome.Chrome'/> -->
  <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.dark.Dark'/>     -->
```

In that case, simply remove the inherit of the theme.

Comment: Yes. I know, No other way to tune off the theme in single line of code or in settings?